# Parsing of video node fails

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

Facebook's Instant Article validator complains that `/html/body/article/header/figure/video: Parsing this node failed. Please verify your formatting` for the code below, and I can't really see anything wrong with it:

`<header>
    <h1>Politimester gikk av etter Monika-saken – har rett til millionlønn «på livstid»</h1>
    <h3 class="op-kicker">«Grov uforstand i tjenesten», konkluderte gransking</h3>
    <p>Geir Gudmundsen (61) er nå rådgiver i Politidirektoratet, men lønnes som politimester. POD bekoster både bolig i Oslo og hjemreisene til Bergen for eks-politimesteren, som er pendler.</p>
    <time class="op-published" datetime="2016-08-30T20:30:37"></time>
    <time class="op-modified" datetime="2016-08-31T09:47:13"></time>
    <figure>
        <video>
            <source src="http://our.secretdomain.com/video.mp4">
        </video>
        <figcaption>Geir Gudmundsen (61) er nå rådgiver i Politidirektoratet, men lønnes som politimester. POD bekoster både bolig i Oslo og hjemreisene til Bergen for eks-politimesteren, som er pendler.</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <address>
        John Doe
    </address>
</header>`

Can anyone spot anything wrong?

Comment: I'm curious, the markup above is what you see in the facebook manager or what you send to facebook (assuming you send it via RSS or the API)?

Comment: This is what I send to Facebook via the RSS-feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the same problem, on all kinds of videos. Rechecked my html a lot of times. Is this a facebook-bug? Also in Norway.

Comment: It's a comfirmed facebook bug. Follow here to get notified about a fix: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1783293851952475/